# Excel 2021 crashes when opening VBA editor and can't load workbooks with macros

Tags: excel, ms-office

I just recently upgraded to Office 2021 (prof. plus LTSC), and whenever I open the VBA editor on Excel, it crashes after few seconds. Moreover, when I try to open any workbook with macros, I get the following message:

"We found a problem with some content in [...]. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes"

when I click yes, the removed content is always the VBA project " /xl/vbaProject.bin ". It occurs in any macro-enabled file I open.

It also occurs in any new macro-enabled workbook that I create

I tried reinstalling Office 2021 and enabling all macros in any workbook. I guess it has nothing to do with the VBA code but some config in excel or windows 10

Where else can I look? Thanks

Comment: This is a pure end-user question which doesn't involve programming at all.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev "software tools commonly used by programmers" is a valid point under [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help]. So since this affects VBA (which you can see at `/xl/vbaProject.bin`) I would consider that as on-topic.

Comment: Just read that *"It also occurs in any new macro-enabled workbook that I create"*. So my answer below might not work and if that is the case it looks more like a Office 2021 issue. Make sure to upgrade to the newest build version. Make sure to run Windows Update aswell. If that all doesn't help call the Micrsoft support.

Answer (score 1):

No this has to do with the file you load beeing corrupted (broken) and Office detected that it is corrupted but obviously wasn't able to repair it.

So it is definitely a problem with the file (and not with Office itself) as Office says in the error message.

So what you can do is:

1. Try opening this file in an old Office version (where it worked before) and save it under a new file name in the binary `xlsb` format. With some luck this gets the file repaired.
2. If (1) did not work: Open the file in an old Office Version, start a new file form scratch. Copy over all macros to the new file, copy over all data to the new file and save it under a new file name. Try to open that new clean file in Office 2021 then.
3. If (2) does not work neither, make sure if creating a new file and copying over the data you copy only values but no formattings.